# I tried to solve but could not develop the left part of the equation

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I tried to solve but could not develop the left part of the equation
[the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omoEr.jpg)

[image]
Thanks

Comment: The summation starting value is a bit unusual, there is a proof here but assumes k=0 to n. https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Sum_of_Binomial_Coefficients_over_Upper_Index

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).